# How can I parse form-data in plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms

I'm trying to create a simple image host in Node.js, but i'm having trouble parsing form-data

The form my test application generates (to upload an image) posts the data in the following format:

```
----------------------8d8317fa35f1280
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ImageUploader"; filename="Test.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<binary PNG data...>

----------------------8d8317fa35f1280--
```

I plan on storing the image data in a key-value database, where the key is an md5 hash of the file, and the value is the raw .png data.

I know that this is very possible with the 'express' javascript framework, but I don't wish to use any frameworks, i'm open to using a library, given that it is fast.

I would like to avoid Regex

How can I parse the filename, and the raw .png data out of this form submission data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a library for parsing such data. [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) is one example, but I would recommend use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Example in multer,

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest:'temp/'}) // path to a temporary folder where files will be saved

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req,res)=>{ // use middleware
    // process file here
    // file will be in req.file
})
```

This one is a very simple example, however multer provides very wide variety of upload methods that you should check.

For getting filename see ***originalname*** property of req.file and for reading file you need to read file ***req.file.path*** which is the actual file

Comment: Why do you recommend multer over formidable? What are the differences

Comment: multer provides you with middleware functions which you can and you will get the file object(s) in the request obect itself. Formidable parses the form data that you have passed as input. Middlewares are cleaner and easy to use and maintan. Also multer provides you with options to set the path, filename and other properties before actually saving the file.